# Access control response headers not sent on bigger files

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

I have a JS application that needs to request 2 JSON files from another domain using asynchronous requests. File 1 being ~400 bytes and file 2 ~10kb. Both files reside in the same directory on the server (say `example.com/files`).

I have also placed an .htaccess file on the server with the following content:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET"
```

When requesting file 1 this all works fine. The response contains both these headers and the file is sent back. With file 2 though, these headers are not in the response, causing the browser to throw an error on violating Same-Origin Policy.

How is this caused (does it have anything to do with the file size?) and of course: how do I fix it?